# Can One for All become too powerful for one person to wield?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The Quirk One for All combines a quirk that stores power and a quirk that can be passed on. Izuku currently has the power and experience of eight previous One for All users, meaning the Quirk grows stronger with each generation. At some point in the very far future, does this mean that One for All will become so powerful, that no one can handle ALL of its power? We already know that it's so powerful now, that a new user can break his limbs off using it. How about in the future, when say 20 more people have passed on the Quirk? Even with training, will the power of this Quirk be too much? Will future users be limited to using a fraction of its power?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Being a Q&A site, not a discussion site, we're a bit intolerant to a speculative question. As of current, this question might (or not) be impossible to answer without any speculation, since in the future any info might change according to the writer and render any existing answers obsolete/incorrect. Thus, this question might get closed as for now, but we're happy to reopen it if anyone can provide a hint on answerable in the comment/flag and thus answer it with facts & references, instead of pure speculation.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question. While users have sometimes voted to close questions which they saw as speculative (because they did not know the answer themselves), I don't think that represents the consensus viewpoint. Taken literally, almost any question could be seen as "speculative" by a sufficiently ignorant person. Questions which ask about ridiculous hypothetical scenarios are one thing, but if it is reasonably possible that the question will have an answer (now or in the future), then simply the fact that you don't know the answer right now is not a reason to vote to close.

Comment: @LoganM . I dont know the answer but I agree with what you've said. I've seen that been the case several times in Anime SE. I think that when we dont know the answer we have to see the answers first and after a while if everything that came out is speculative vote to close it. Plus many times answers arent only in manga and anime, but in producers/writers/creators interviews or tweets, production notes, anime guides, tv specials which arent widely known  etc.

Comment: If it continues to pass to other people and stack up more power, it is likely, that this will happen at some point. But it is questionable, if that will ever be a part of the story line.

Comment: I don't believe there can be answer which is not speculation. It is not completely clear how One for All works at all. Who knows, maybe quirk itself allows user to extend limits of his body.